# Android Service Threading

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service, android-asynctask

I have a Service, in which I wish to do a series of intensive tasks (uploading bitmaps to some server)

Assuming the upload function is

```
uploadImage(Bitmap bitmap);
```

WHat is the best approach for this?

At first I did it like thus (bearing in mind there could be a dozen or so elements of array ImageMakers):

```
for (MyImageMaker mim : ImageMakers){
      uploadImage(mim.getImage());
}
```

My reasoning was, that since I'm not using the UI thread I don't need to put this series of intensive tasks on another thread.
But then I thought maybe I should use a ThreadPoolExecutor, to speed things up a bit.

```
  ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor)Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);//5 is arbitrary
   for (MyImageMaker mim : ImageMakers){

 executor.execute(new Runnable(){
      public void run(){
        uploadImage(mim.getImage());
     } 
     }   
  }
```

My first questions is, is this a good idea?

Then I thought I want to call some other function after the last image is uploaded. Using a ThreadPoolExecutor, what is the best way to do this?

Not knowing the best way, I settled for an AsyncTask.

```
 private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{


      protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

          for (MyImageMaker mim : ImageMakers){
                    uploadImage(mim.getImage());
             }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
        anotherFunction();//needs to be called after all images uploaded

    }
}
```

I would like to know which technique is best. Or if there is a better way to do a series of intensive tasks in a Service.

Comment: **"My reasoning was, that since I'm not using the UI thread"** - An Android `Service` runs on the main (UI) thread and will block with the potential of an ANR. Using `AsyncTask` in a `Service` is basically pointless as all methods (except `doInBackground(...)`) are designed to interact with the UI (not possible with a `Service`). Use an `IntentService` as Ponyets suggests - an `IntentService` manages its own worker thread and self-terminates when finished.

Comment: @Squonk - You are correct. So do yuo suggest I do a simple loop in an IntentService?

Comment: That would work depending on your requirements. I use an `IntentService` the other way around - I need to download a number of files and pass a list of URLs which my `IntentService` loops through. The `IntentService` is either called by an `AlarmManager` alarm (possibly when the device is asleep) and generates a `Notification` on completion. It can also be triggered manually from an `Activity` which creates and passes a `ResultReceiver` to get interactive feedback. There are a number of ways of doing it but `IntentService` is a useful and powerful class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) is a better way.

```
protected void onHandleIntent(){
    for (MyImageMaker mim : ImageMakers){
        uploadImage(mim.getImage());
    }
}
```

Comment: But should I use a ThreadPoolExecutor to make it more efficient?

Comment: Use ThreadPoolExecutor may be more efficient. ThreadPoolExecutor would be better than AsyncTask, cause AsyncTasks on system before 1.6 or after 3.0 run in series.